# JS Combining RegEx with While Loop

Tags: javascript, regex, while-loop

Trying to search for specific text and check if it exists in the line. If it does Display "Yes", if no then display "No".

Currently what I have:

```
const str = `Hello my name is Stack Overlow.`
const publish = /Hello/g;
    let pub;
    while ((pub = publish.exec(str)) !== null) {
        if (pub.index === publish.lastIndex) {
            publish.lastIndex++;
        }
        pub.forEach((ko, groupIndex) => {
            document.write(`"Exists": "${ko}",<br>`);
        });
    }
```

Comment: There is no question. Also, where is the "Yes" and "No" in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var string = 'Hello my name is not important';
var pattern = /Hello/g;

if(pattern.test(string)) {
  console.log('yes');
}
else {
  console.log('no');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with `indexOf()` if you're not particularly keen on RegExes:

```js
const str = 'Hello my name is Stack Overlow.'
const containsSubstring = (string, substring) => ~string.indexOf(substring) ? 'Yes' : 'No';

console.log(containsSubstring(str, 'Hello')); // 'Yes'
```

I've also wrapped the check in an anonymous function `containsSubstring`. This will avoid repetition if you are trying to check for other substrings later on, as you can call `containsSubstring` with any string/substring pair without rewriting your code or repeating yourself.